# Error updating scheduled query: update_time cannot be updated

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to update a schedule query (modifying SQL code) I get this error: Error updating scheduled query: update_time cannot be updated.

I think that previously I made this kind of updates without problems... Any idea what could be happening now?

Comment: Having the exact same issue here, it seems like I can't update any query SQL code. In addition to that I can't modify the scheduled runtime nor disable any query without deleting it.
I used to perform these actions without having any issues and something happened a day or two ago.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: I updated this same query last week, so my suspicion is something is broken on  the GCP side

Comment: We are also facing same problem, not sure by when we can completely start trusting on this service. its really becoming a trouble as we had chosen this over other schedulers for its easiness and native solution.

Comment: Check out Magnus - Workflow Automator which is part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com) Suite - supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc.. Also available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio). Disclosure: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have also found out that currently is not possible to disable current scheduled queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fix fully deployed for the previous bug. Already tested in BigQuery web UI and works fine.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue already reported to the BigQuery engineering team.

You can track the progress of the research regarding this issue [in this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145095845). It seems an issue with the BigQuery UI as the Classic UI [seems to be working](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145095845#comment3)

I suggest [starring](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) the issue to indicate you're being affected by this issue.

**UPDATE**

The classic UI [may have issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145095845#comment5) regarding the dataset destination set.

I consider recreating the scheduled query would be the best workaround while the fix is released.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24692843)

Comment: What you mean? this is an identified issue in the BigQuery product and it's being address at the moment

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko
This answers the authors question exactly.  The question was "Any idea what could be happening now?"
And This answer is: an issue within BigQuery (which has already been reported to the BigQuery engineering team).  F10 Also kindly included a link to the actual Issue Tracker so you can vote and watch progress of the issue being resolved.

Comment: Please add more details regarding the issue, rather than just linking to it. Link-only answers may be downvoted or deleted at any time without further warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a new bug in Scheduled Queries of GCP. Is it important to remember that this tool is on BETA yet.

Since a few months, I'm creating and updating queries and using a lot this tool and yesterday was the first time that I was faced to this message.

[GCP Scheduled Queries error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1JPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the answer.  But for CLI based update you can try following -
Get the transfer config location (us\asia) for the scheduled query-
bq ls \

> --transfer_config \
>   --transfer_location=

Execute bq update 
bq update \
--transfer_config \
--schedule='every xx minutes'

Above is just an example, you can update the update values for what you need to modify in the scheduled query.