# Error when trying to update scheduled query in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I created a scheduled query in BigQuery with the user interface that I was able to update if needed. Now, when I try to update this scheduled query, It does not work and I have the following error

> update_time cannot be updated.

Does anyone knows why I can no longer update this scheduled query or faced the same problem ?

Comment: Can you share the current configuration of the query that you want to update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error updating scheduled query: update\_time cannot be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028081/error-updating-scheduled-query-update-time-cannot-be-updated)

Comment: Hello guillaume blaquiere,
Sorry for the late response. It is working as usual now.