# BigQuery not letting me update scheduled queries

Tags: google-bigquery

Not sure if this is a user error or a bug on the platform, but I am no longer able to update scheduled queries. I used to be able to open the query in the editor, change some code, then update scheduled query to save the change. Now I am getting this error:

Error updating scheduled query: update_time cannot be updated.

Has anybody else run into this?

[Error Message Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gutFE.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error updating scheduled query: update\_time cannot be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028081/error-updating-scheduled-query-update-time-cannot-be-updated)